# Terraform: Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character ']' looking for beginning of value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting an error when try to implement this policy:

> Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character ']' looking for beginning of value

Could someone explain faced this issue on how to fix it?

```
policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1704624583452",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1704622653819",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/*"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.override_default_setting]
}
POLICY
}
```

Expecting to get rid of this error and implement the policy on a S3 bucket.

Comment: I cleaned-up the formatting of your policy. You'll see that there are mismatched curly-brackets. Also, the `depends_on` should _NOT_ be inside the `POLICY` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JSON validator if you're having issues. Here is valid JSON to work with:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1704624583452",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1704622653819",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jenkins-prj01-s3bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: │ Error: putting S3 Bucket (jenkins-prj01-s3bucket) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: F5FDY6ABC5D3G4F5, HostID: NhyFijzzU5MIfFWDtiuN7hPGo5qCdQUI1PihUOlDUg2AuLrPXM/MlXjmnlASRPhmx6MsJABpsZw=, api error MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource
│ 
│   with aws_s3_bucket_policy.jenkins-prj1-cloudstore-policy,
│   on Main.tf line 73, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "jenkins-prj1-cloudstore-policy":
│   73: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "jenkins-prj1-cloudstore-policy" {

Comment: I am getting above error when I move forward.

Comment: Thanks for your directions as earlier syntax error was now fixed